# Using hash table in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, hash

I want to create an application in which a lookup table (in excel) needs to be given as an input to the application. This lookup table maps script names to its run time details. In my application i want to access the run time associated with the script name that user provides.

Code :

```
    $hash = @{}
   $xl = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
   $wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("$data_path\Lookup_Table.xlsm")
   $ws = $wb.WorkSheets.Item(1)
   $ws.activate()
   $objRange = $ws.UsedRange
   $RowCount = $objRange.Rows.Count
   for ($k=0; $k -lt $RowCount; $k++) 
      {
         $fullname = $ws.cells.item(2+$k,1) 
         $time = $ws.cells.item(2+$k,2)
        $hash.Set_Item($fullname,$time)
      }
   $wb.Save()
   $wb.Close()
   $xl.Quit()
   [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
   Stop-Process -Name EXCEL -Force
```

Still the $hash is not taking the value 
`$hash.Get_Item($name)` command outputs nothing. 
I tired with all the three methods which i knew

```
             $hash[$fullname] = $time
             $hash.Add($fullname , $time)
             $hash.Set_Item($fullname,$time)
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: Are you certain that `$time` has a value?

Comment: The 3 methods work with harcoded test values.

Comment: So how can the values be entered in hash table?

Comment: Is this all in one script?   If not, you could have a scoping issue.  Also, PowerShell supports the following syntax for adding to a hashtable: `$hash += @{ $key = $value}`, which also supports adding multiple items in one operation.